# Self-taught networking. How do you get examples?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this question would be on topic, so I'm asking here first, so it could be answered or re asked on the forum, or just removed.

I've been watching videos and reading about networking. My actual knowledge spans Basic devices and Configuration, How to patch cables, osi and tcp/ip models, and also have some knowledge about servers and devices specs.

But I can't very well imagine how is it to think a complete network for a small business or house. Is there any place where I could find examples so I can really bundle concepts together?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for almost every SE site, including Network Engineering.

There are hundreds of network learning sites on the public Internet, including online network racks and labs with exercises.

Comment: thanks! any you recommend for a beginner, and more focused on the practical side?

Answer (score 1):

As Ron points out, this would not be an appropriate question for the main site. However, you could always ask on chat for the site as the rules for what is on/off topic is generally much more relaxed on any site's chat channels.

Comment: Great, I will. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To know the complete network architecture of medium-to-small-sized companies, you need to have experience and practical work experience working on such networks. In order for engineers to gain a better understanding